# Alternative for deprecated apache commons CurveFitter class?

Tags: java, deprecated, curve-fitting, apache-commons-math

The `org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.fitting.CurveFitter` is [deprecated](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/fitting/CurveFitter.html).

It was a useful class. Why was it deprecated?

The docs don't say what we should use instead. What is the alternative class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package-level javadoc explains:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/package-summary.html

Basically, the entire `org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.*` tree is being reworked.

The direct replacement class for `CurveFitter` is [`org.apache.commons.math3.fitting.AbstractCurveFitter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fitting/AbstractCurveFitter.html).

Why?  You would need to trawl through the issue tracker and developer mailing lists to find that out.